# xamarin android nuggetPackage dependencies monoAndroid

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, dependencies

I'm developping a Xamarin Android app and i'm facing a problem which seems to be a problem of nugget package dependencies :

- Microsoft.Office365.OAuth.Xamarin V1.0.21

  - Dependencies :

    - MonoAndroid, Version v2.2
- Xamarin.Android.Support.V4 V23.3

  - Dependencies :

    - MonoAndroid, Version v7.0

Whenever I try to build my project :

`error: cannot find symbol android.support.v4.content.Loader.OnLoadCanceledListener`

This error come from this java file

<%Project%>\obj\Release\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\content\Loader_OnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor.java

```
package mono.android.support.v4.content;

public class Loader_OnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor
extends java.lang.Object
implements
    mono.android.IGCUserPeer,
    // this line is making the build fails
    android.support.v4.content.Loader.OnLoadCanceledListener
    ...
    ...
```

Morever, these packages work perfectly when they aren't added together.

Am I doing something wrong ?